# Secure Token Passing in Ajax in a Highly Cached Environment

Tags: ajax, security, access-token

Greetings SO Community!

I'm trying to think through a security issue with an ajax process in a highly cached environment, and could use some advice. My situation is this:

- The users of the site are not logged in.
- The site pages are highly cached (via akamai).
- I have a service API that is to be accessed via AJAX from pages within my domain.
- I need to protect that API from being used outside of my domain.

I can check the incoming "host" in the headers to see if the ajax request came from my domain, but that seems insecure, as such headers could be spoofed. Also, it seems to me that the usual token passing scheme will not work for me because my pages are cached, so I don't have the opportunity to inject tokens unique to the user/request (e.g. as described here: [How can I restrict access to some PHP pages only from pages within my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784513/how-can-i-restrict-access-to-some-php-pages-only-from-pages-within-my-website)). Clearly, it's insecure to make a token request via ajax after page load, so I'm not sure how to make this happen. I suppose I could generate a shared use token that loads with the page and has a lifetime twice that of my maximum page cache life, but it seems like there *must* be a better way!

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to prevent cross site request forgery or someone\something from using your API that is not the javascript you served to the user?

The former is accomplished via tokens that are stored in the source of the page. You can make it hard to conduct an XSRF attack by having tokens in the source ( or some code that creates tokens). Unfortunately, unless you can get unique data per user/request into the source, someone can always just grab your source and reverse engineer the token. Then they can forge requests. The general rule is don't worry about it unless the user is loged in because the attacker could just go to the page themselves.

The later(preventing unauthorized use) is impossible in anycase. An attacker can always make an account, strip the tokens/keys/credentials she needs, and then use some API on their server.